# how to fix winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.2~hirsute-1)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

i am running Feren Os a branch of Ubuntu and I have a new problem while installing Winehq
the system is up to date and all packages upgrade except for one .

```
$ sudo apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
vkd3d-compiler/hirsute 1.2~hirsute-1 i386 [upgradable from: 1.2~focal-1]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6yHk.png)
[wine Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tYNW.png)

```
$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.2~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried

```
$ sudo dpkg --force depends -P wine-stable
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove wine-stable which isn't installed

$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed Feren Os based on Ubuntu Focal with Ubuntu Hirsute leading to the `unmet dependencies` error.

To fix this problem, you need to remove `hirsute` from `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` dir.

To install winehq [see the documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) and use the `focal` codename.

If you have an issue with `vkd3d`, it can be installed from [Cybermax](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecybermax-dexter/+archive/ubuntu/vkd3d) PPA..

Answer (score 0):

Synaptic -> removed all wine repositories

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt update
```

Removing previous WineHQ repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
```

Adding other repositories:

```
wget -q https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/Release.key -O Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04/ ./'

sudo apt-get update
```

But!

The final suggested step with wine-stable:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends **winehq-devel**
```

.. This worked for me on kali after having trouble installing wine